# Date parsing with sub method

Tags: parsing, time, go

I'm aware of the time package and how you can parse templates based on date/time representation.  What I would like to know is how to parse time.Now() one month prior to stdLongMonth.

i.e.

```
time.Now() // == April, 2013
// Output: March, 2013
```

In other words, is it possible to parse time.now() with a sub.stdLongMonth() method? Can anyone be kind enough and show some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    y, m, _ := time.Now().Date()
    t := time.Date(y, m, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t.Format("January, 2006"))
    t = time.Date(y, m-1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Println(t.Format("January, 2006"))
}
```

Output:

```
April, 2013
March, 2013
```

Comment: Excellent!  the time package is a bit different from what I'm used to.  TY Peter

Answer (score -1):

use time.AddDate() as this will also free you from timezone considerations:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    time := time.Now().AddDate(0,-1,0)
    fmt.Println(time.Format("January, 2006"))

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. For example, if the time.Now() date is 2013-03-31 the result is 2013-03-03 and the output is March, 2013, not February, 2013. AddDate normalizes its result.